# Adobe version control software?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, version-control, adobe-illustrator, adobe-creative-suite

Does the Adobe CS suite of products come with a version control system that integrates natively with products such as Illustrator / Photoshop allowing action and/or layer level specific version control?

Is there software for this or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yes, there was [Version Cue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Version_Cue).

> Version Cue enables users to track and manipulate file versions and metadata. Users can see previews of older versions and can restore or delete versions at any time.

It integrates with Adobe Bridge. Note that – as far as I am concerned – it does not have "layer" specific version control. The only drawback anyway is that Adobe discontinued it with CS5.

> Users of CS5 may continue to access a Version Cue Server from CS3 or CS4 with WebDAV.

For more info you can read the [Adobe Drive 2 FAQ](http://www.adobe.com/products/adobedrive/).

Comment: What does Adobe Bridge do? And what exactly is Drive 2? I looked over that FAQ and didn't really seem to have it jive. Or is it just Cue was "free" and now Drive makes you pay additional?

Comment: Bridge is a media manager integrated into the Adobe Creative Suite.  Drive is a digital asset management client, and requires a [CMIS Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services).  Version Cue Server is one such (discontinued) server that Drive can connect to.  Drive replaces the Version Cue Client from previous Creative Suites.

Comment: @Chris You should know Bridge if you have Photoshop or Illustrator. As afrazier said, the other stuff is a bit difficult to set up.

Comment: I'm a software developer, I've never had a reason to use bridge (or never had a need because I still don't really understand the purpose of a "media manager")

Comment: I know what you're saying -- I just meant, "it's there, so you can try it" @chris

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is [PixelNovel's Timeline](http://pixelnovel.com/timeline).  It's not free, but it uses a standard Subversion repository and integrates with Photoshop, Illustrator, and InDesign.  Dreamweaver has it's own Subversion capabilities built-in.

It's not layer level specific either.  I doubt that most such tools would be, because most will be designed to operate on the entire Photoshop file.  Anything that did what you wanted would be so PS-specific and tightly bound that the repositories would probably only hold PS blobs.  Repositories would be PS-version specific and probably ultimately unusable outside of PS itself.  Considering that most people don't work in a Photoshop vacuum, something like that would be less useful than a program that could integrate with the entire suite and could storage and manage all the associated files with a particular project.